# Why am I getting error in the ArrayList while trying to put an instance in putParcelableArrayList?

Tags: android, android-room, bundle

So, I am trying to pass the data of all the saved cardviews into and show them in another fragment (ToLearnFragment.kt) so when I click on the star icon the data gets stored. so I am using room database for it, i have created the Room database and also created the repository and the viewmodel required and finally when i try to pass the data through bundle using putParcelableArrayList I am getting an error in it's value.

FlashCardData.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "flashcards")
data class FlashcardData(
    val front:String,
    val back:String,
)
```

FlashcardsDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface FlashCardsDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertFlashcard(flashcard: FlashcardData)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM flashcards")
    fun getAllFlashcards(): LiveData<List<FlashcardData>>
}
```

Below is the Room Database class
FlashcardRoomDatabase.kt

```
@Database(entities = [FlashCards::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class FlashCardRoomDatabase:RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun flashCardsDao():FlashCardsDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var instance:FlashCardRoomDatabase?=null

        fun getDatabase(context:Context):FlashCardRoomDatabase{
            val tempInstance = instance
            if(tempInstance!=null){
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this){
                val INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    FlashCardRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "flashcard_database"
                ).build()
                instance=INSTANCE
                return INSTANCE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The repository class
WordRepository.kt

```
class WordRepository(@Inject private val flashCardsDao: FlashCardsDao) {

    val allwords: LiveData<List<FlashcardData>> = flashCardsDao.getAllFlashcards()

    suspend fun insertFlashCard(flashCards:FlashcardData){
        flashCardsDao.insertFlashcard(flashCards)
    }

    suspend fun getAllWords(){
    flashCardsDao.getAllFlashcards()
}
    
}
```

below is my ViewModel class
FlashcardviewModel.kt

```
class FlashcardViewModel(application: Application,@Inject private var repository: WordRepository):AndroidViewModel(application) {


    init {
        val flashCardsDao = FlashCardRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application).flashCardsDao()
        repository = WordRepository(flashCardsDao)
    }
    val allFlashcards: LiveData<List<FlashcardData>> = repository.allwords

    fun insertFlashCard(flashCards: FlashcardData) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insertFlashCard(flashCards)
    }

    fun getAllWords() = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getAllWords()
    }


}
```

My Fragment class
QuestionsFragment.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class QuestionsFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentQuestionsBinding
    lateinit var viewModel: BottomNavigationViewModel
    lateinit var counterviewModel:ToLearnViewModel
    lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
    lateinit var flashcardviewModel: FlashcardViewModel

    private val hashMap = HashMap<String,String>()

    private var currentPairIndex =0
    private lateinit var currentPair:Map.Entry<String,String>

    var isFront=true
    private val totalPairs = 17 // change the value to the actual number of entries in your hashMap

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentQuestionsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        bottomNavigationView = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[BottomNavigationViewModel::class.java]
        counterviewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[ToLearnViewModel::class.java]
        flashcardviewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[FlashcardViewModel::class.java]

        bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE

        binding.textCounter.text = counterviewModel.count.toString()



        // setting up listener for back Icon
        binding.backIcon?.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }

        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_questionsFragment_to_flashCards)
        }

        //changing color of progress bar progress
        binding.progressHorizontal.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext()
            ,R.color.blue_card))

        //changing color of background color of progress bar
        binding.progressHorizontal.progressBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),
        R.color.silver))

        // Hashmap of strings that will shown on cardview front and back side
        hashMap["What"] = "Kas"
        hashMap["When"] = "Kai"
        hashMap["Where"] = "Kur"
        hashMap["Who"] = "Kas"
        hashMap["Whom"] = "Kam"
        hashMap["Why"] = "Kodėl"
        hashMap["How"] = "Kaip"
        hashMap["Which"] = "Kuris/kuri"
        hashMap["Whose"] = "Kieno"
        hashMap["I"] = "aš"
        hashMap["you (singular)"] = "tu/jūs (informal/formal)"
        hashMap["he"] = "jis"
        hashMap["she"] = "ji"
        hashMap["it "] = "tai"
        hashMap["we"] = "mes"
        hashMap["you (plural)"] = "jūs"
        hashMap["they"] = "jie"

       val front_animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.anim.front_animator) as AnimatorSet
        val back_animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,R.anim.back_animator)as AnimatorSet

        // retrieve the current pair from the hashMap
        currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)
        binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
        binding.textCardBack.text = hashMap[currentPair.key]


        // onclick listener on the image
        binding.imageFlashCard.setOnClickListener {
            counterviewModel.addWordCount()
            binding.textCounter.text = counterviewModel.count.toString()
            // increment currentPairIndex and get the next pair
            currentPairIndex++
            if (currentPairIndex >= hashMap.size) {
                // if we have reached the end of the hashmap, start again from the beginning
                currentPairIndex = 0
            }
            currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)

            // update the UI with the new pair
            binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
            binding.textCardBack.text = hashMap[currentPair.key]

            //store data in the room database
            val flashCards = FlashcardData(front = currentPair.key, back = hashMap[currentPair.key]!!)
            flashcardviewModel.insertFlashCard(flashCards)

            // retrieve all the data from the Room Database and pass it to the LearnFragment
            val allFlashCards = flashcardviewModel.getAllWords()

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("flashcards",ArrayList(allFlashCards)) // I am getting error here at ArrayList(allFlashCards)

            val learnFragment = ToLearnFragment()
            learnFragment.arguments = bundle
        }

        //Onclick listener for the counterButton
        binding.cardLearning.setOnClickListener {
            // navigate to the LearnFragment
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_questionsFragment_to_toLearnFragment)
        }

        //onclick listener for the Flip button
        with(binding) {
            btnFlip.setOnClickListener {
                val progress = ((currentPairIndex + 1) * 100) / totalPairs
                binding.progressHorizontal.progress = progress

                // initialize currentPairIndex to 0 if it hasn't been initialized yet
                if (currentPairIndex < 0) {
                    currentPairIndex = 0
                }
                if (isFront) {
                    front_animation.setTarget(textCardFront)
                    back_animation.setTarget(textCardBack)
                    front_animation.start()
                    back_animation.start()
                    isFront = false
                    textCardBack.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textCardFront.visibility = View.GONE
                    imageFlashCard.visibility = View.GONE
                    cardViewQuestions.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pink))

                } else {
                    currentPairIndex = (currentPairIndex + 1) % hashMap.size
                    textCardFront.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textCardBack.visibility = View.GONE
                    imageFlashCard.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    cardViewQuestions.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.blue_card))
                    front_animation.setTarget(textCardBack)
                    back_animation.setTarget(textCardFront)
                    back_animation.start()
                    front_animation.start()
                    isFront = true
                }
                // retrieve the current pair from the hashMap
                currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)
                binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
                binding.textCardBack.text = hashMap[currentPair.key]
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```